# Unable to connect to MySQL in Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am unable to connect to database. My credentials are correct. I was able to connect using Oracle SQL Developer. I am getting the error below. Any help will be appreciated.

```
> INFO: Loaded JDBC driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
Jul 24, 2012 2:38:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://XX.1.1.XX:3306/dashboard
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:381)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:455)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:463)
    at com.mvc.services.TransactionInfoService.getData(TransactionInfoService.java:39)
    at com.mvc.controllers.MainController.handleRequestInternal(MainController.java:29)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
```

I have included the Java code along with the error any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

```java
package com.mvc.services;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;

import com.mvc.interfaces.DataInterface;
import com.mvc.objects.TransactionInfo;

public class TransactionInfoService implements DataInterface {
    private String info;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void connect() {
        // Connect To Database
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        // dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dashboard");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://xx.1.1.xx:3306/dashboard");
        // dataSource.setUsername("username");
        // dataSource.setPassword("admin");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        setDataSource(dataSource);
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have set the driver class name to `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver` but yet are attempting to connect to a MySQL database. The driver for MySQL is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Comment: I tried that too, actually its working for my coworker with com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver thats why I tried but for me I tried both and its not working.

Comment: Not possible. Download the driver from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/.

Comment: Thanks, Reimeus I did downloaded the mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar from the site. And its in Apache lib folder. I do see some other file with the download is their any special process. I dont see README.txt useful to me.

Comment: Do a simple connect test first with no Spring and the MySQL jar in the classpath. e.g. http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/

Comment: Reimeus, I was able to sucessfylly connect to my database using the example you gave. But I still don't understand why I am not able to connect in my app. One questions jdbc jar file is in Apache Lib does it need to be in somewhere else.??

Comment: I do have jar in WEB-INF/lib as well. And the error is:                   exception 

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://10.1.1.22:3306/dashboard

Comment: Thank  you every one. The problem has been solved. I have no idea what caused the issue but it ran this time. I didn't changed anything.